# Do I need to do something specific if I want my Facebook app to auto-publish on a user stream after the user install/allow the app?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I am wondering if I need to do something in particular if I want my facebook app to auto-publish on a user wall after the user install/allow the app?

Does facebook app auto-publish automatically when someone install/allow?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have “Social Discovery” activated in your app settings, it will happen automatically when Facebook thinks it is appropriate – AFAIK that means more than anything else that there already has to be a solid user base for your app, before these feed stories start showing for new users.